# ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block when trying to import a raster image to postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql-12, postgis-raster

I am getting the following error when trying to import a raster image to a PostGIS DB using raster2pgsql.

ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

I have tried a number of different solutions without any luck.

OS is Windows 10
PostgreSQL version 12

This is my command

```
raster2pgsql -s 32735 -I -C -M C:\Users\jaunv\Dropbox\share2server\postgis\2020-09-26-00_00_2020-09-26-23_59_Sentinel-2_L2A_Moisture_index.tiff -F -t 250x250 public.raster | psql -d geofarm -U postgres -p 5432
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run without `-C` constraints

and with `-e` for executing without transaction

Does table public.raster exist and has any data?

also for clean experiment it is better to insert into empty table

https://helpmanual.io/help/raster2pgsql/

Comment: Thank you that has solved the problem to a certain extent. But now it seems like there is another issue. After running the command without the C and with the e it seems like the image is processed but at the end gives the following error.                                      
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
ERROR:  function st_convexhull(raster) does not exist
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX ON "public"."raster11" USING gist (st_convexhul...                                                        HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.